# Does sed/awk work for this? Use something else instead?

Tags: ruby, sed, awk

I want to be able to do something like this quickly:

I have a MySQL database table with visitors to my site. The columns are date, IP address, browser, URL, referer.

I want to do this:

1. grab all the rows during a particular day
2. delete all rows, making sure that in each 15-minute interval, no two rows have the same IP address

Is sed/awk suitable for these kinds of problems? Or would some scripting language such as Ruby be more appropriate?

I don't quite "get" what sed/awk is actually for. Feel free to briefly explain that as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sed and Awk are meant as text processing tools. Therefore, they can help in situations where your data is presented in a nice text format (generally equivalent to human-readable).

An SQL database is generally stored in a binary format, for which these tools are **not** the best option. Even some formats that are human readable are better off with other tools (XML is probably the best example).

If you could export your database as a CSV (comma separated value spreadsheet), you might have a better chance to process it with these tools.

Otherwise, it's way easier to use Perl/Python/Ruby with a suitable SQL module to access the data.

Hope this helps =)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use SQL for this purpose. Thats why you stored the data in a database in the first place isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

[Sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) or [Awk](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) are not appropriate for this problem they are for text processing. I would recommend using either `Python` or `PHP` combined with the relevant `SQL` library/module and use [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to schedule the execution of the script. The scripts would be along the lines of this *(for php).*

```
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'mysql_user'
$db_pwd = 'supersecret'

$Date = '10/3/2010' #Whatever the date format is in the DB 
mysqlconnect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db.table WHERE time=$Date);

while (!$row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    echo $row

# Should check IP before deletion - **WARNING** Will delete all data from table
mysql_query("DELETE FROM db.table")

mysql_free_result($result)
```

Note: this doesn't do the row checking beforing deleting but you get the idea of how to start developing something.